# Searching one Google Sheet to add a row of data to another

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

I searched and was able to find some similar questions like this, but I wasn't able to find exactly what I'm looking for and I wasn't able to use the formulas in the other questions to make this work. So sorry in advance if this has been asked before!!

Basically, I have multiple Google Sheet files (about 12 in total). Here I'll call them "Master", "Client1", Client2" and so on. For simplicity, I've just named the sheets within the files to be "Sheet1" :)

The column headers in each spreadsheet are "Brand" "Client Name", "Client Location", "Client Email", , etc... In the "Client1", Client2", etc... workbooks the first column will always be the same as the filename.

The "Master" workbook contains information on all of the clients and what "Brand" they work for (or in some cases, which *Brands* they work for, which makes this tricky).

[Here is a picture of the "Master" workbook as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS8Pc.png)

As pictured, some have multiple Brands, all are different clients, locations, emails.

[This is what the Client1 workbook looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaPO9.png)

but I need a formula to insert into the Client1 workbook and search the first column of Master workbook and then display data if column A in Master contains "Client1"

[So basically here is what Client1 would need to look like when all is said and done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5XnC.png)

I've tried things like `=IFERROR`, `=vlookup`, `=RegExMatch` and can't get any of them to work. I know it has to be something simple that I'm doing wrong, but I'm at my wit's end.

Any and all help would be AMAZING!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if this is your master:**

[image]

**then:**

```
={TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("client1 ", COUNTA(
  QUERY(QUERY(master!A2:D, "select *", 0), 
  "select Col2,Col3,Col4
   where Col1 contains 'client1'", 0))/3)," ")), 
  QUERY(QUERY(master!A2:D, "select *", 0), 
  "select Col2,Col3,Col4 
   where Col1 contains 'client1'", 0)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My only question would be how to do that across different workbooks. Unfortunately they have to be split up into different google sheet docs and not just all as different sheets within the same doc. So "Master" and "Client1" are the names of the actual files, the sheets (for now) are just Sheet1. I assume a well placed "IMPORTRANGE" would do the trick, but not sure how exactly

Comment: Thanks for the update (and sorry about the slow reply). I was able to get the importrange to work, however I'm running into a different error. After reviewing your example above it looks as though you did as well.

After the formula runs, the output is indeed pulling some of the Client1 data from the Master sheet, but it is pulling duplicates and isn't pulling all of the results. 

So it should be pulling Rob Sam Ted George and Howard, it is only pulling Rob, Sam Rob Rob and Howard.

Comment: Thanks again!!!

Comment: Great, thanks! I hate to even ask, but how would you implement IMPORTRANGE back into the new formula?

Comment: @ProfC just change `master!A2:D` to `IMPORTRANGE("ID-or-URL", "master!A2:D")`

Comment: Perfect! I'll go test it now and let you know if I have any questions. Though this all looks AMAZING!!

Comment: Last question, I swear (well, I hope...). If I need to add additional columns (right now I have A:N, but more may be added in the future. I attempted to add more by updating this part of the formula:

  "select Col2,Col3,Col4
   where Col1 contains 'client1'", 0))/3)," ")), 

to:

  "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8
   where Col1 contains 'client1'", 0))/7)," ")),

It works up to Col8 (A:H), however, if I add more than Col8 I get a ref error "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected 15, Actual 17. 

Any ideas?

Comment: That is a bit tricky, as the actual sheet has confidential info and I can't PM on here. Suggestions?

Comment: Ignore that, I made a quick copy with personal data removed. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qgHw24FoftilBZT-FvzLld8nBWWpFevyXhB1HWxOxc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is working on the first sheet tab, second (with one more Column added) it fails. Also, here is the link to where it is pulling the data from: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pkwzUGyJbgHfpq7cOWFJh12g7FnsXXbvT48QcAB0ZkE/edit#gid=1462686065

Comment: @ProfC done, see your sheet